# Interactive Grid - JavaScript getValue

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-18.2

I’m struggling to obtain the new value that is being set in an editable Interactive Grid. I’ve created a dynamic action to be fired when the column has *changed*. The dynamic action is firing as expected, but it’s returning the previous value and not the value that triggered the event.

The dynamic action is set to execute JavaScript:

```
var $te = $(this.triggeringElement);
var rowID = $te.closest('tr').data('id');
var grid = apex.region('IG_SCALE_1').call('getViews','grid');
var model = grid.model;
var record = model.getRecord(rowID);
var column_val = model.getValue(record,”COLUMN_1”);

apex.item(“P1_HIDDEN_1”).setValue(column_val);
```

Let’s say column_1 *had* a value of 0 and that value was changed to 1. The code is setting the hidden item’s value to 0. I need it to be set to 1.

When I execute the following code I can see the old value in the array.

```
console.log(record);
```

Is there anything that I can do to obtain the new value?

Many thanks.. let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be encountering one of the bugs, which are fixed in APEX version 19.2.

John Snyders described in his blog [APEX IG Cookbook update for 19.2](https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2019/11/04/apex-ig-cookbook-update-for-19-2/)

> *One of the bugs had to do with changes to the last edited cell not always being saved.*

A list of all fixed bugs in 19.2 is available here: [APEX 19.2 Release Notes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/htmrn/index.html#HTMRN-GUID-A7400F11-3C2B-4391-901A-1782C21335C4).
Search for **26963177** and **29132960** in particular.

Can you reproduce the issue in [apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com) environment?